# ツリー構造のシリアライズ化

Tags: unity3d, c#

ツリー構造をシリアライズ化しようとした所、以下のようなエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

```
Serialization depth limit exceeded at 'Node'. There may be an object composition cycle in one or more of your serialized classes.
```

内容的にはシリアライズかする際の深さ制限が無いからダメのようです。
明示的に深さ制限を設けても構わないので、この問題を回避する方法をご存じないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Node {
    public Node[] Children;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記のページの
「私はUnityのシリアライザがサポートしていないオブジェクトをシリアライズしたいです。何をすればいいですか？」
という項目に、ISerializationCallbackReceiverを実装してツリー構造をListへ平坦化してシリアライズさせるソースコードがあるので参考になるかもしれません。

http://japan.unity3d.com/blog/?p=1630

Comment: ありがとうございます。  

ツリー構造のシリアライズ化にはこんな方法があったんですね。  

まさにやりたい事はこんな感じでした！

Comment: @Hironoi Itoさん、回答が気に入って問題が解決した場合には、その回答を承認することができます。詳しくはヘルプセンターをご参照ください。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

[`NonSerializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) で特定のフィールドをシリアル化対象外にすることが出来ます。

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Node
{
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public Node[] Children;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
確かにこの方法だとエラー自体は出なくなるのですが、そもそもシリアライズ化されなくなってしまうので、何か良い方法がないかと検討していました。

Comment: @HironoriIto なるほど。自己参照でない配列要素はシリアライズしたい感じだったのですね。